# Is $2^9$ the only power of two that is the sum of two odd perfect powers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, perfect-powers

Let $m\ge 1$ be an integer.

> For which $m$ can we find odd perfect powers $a,b$ with $a+b=2^m$ ? The only solution, I found for $m\le 80$ is $m=9$ with the representation $$2^9=13^2+7^3$$

The exponents cannot be both even because the sum of two odd squares is congruent $2$ modulo $4$. Can we prove that no other power of $2$ does the job ? If the question is too difficult, can at least the case $p^2+q^3$ be solved with elliptic-curve-properties ?

Comment: Is this a counter-example to the Beal Conjecture? $\longrightarrow$ https://www.bealconjecture.com/

Comment: @user477343 No, one exponent is $2$

Comment: Ah yes, the exponents must be greater than $2$... hahah sorry about that

Comment: @user477343 Actually, if all solutions related to the fermat-catalan-conjecture are known, this implies that $2^9$ is the only power doing the job.

Comment: Why do you exclude $2^2=3^1 + 1^1?$

Comment: @gammatester   Usually, the perfect powers do not include $1$, but I can clarify that if you want. However, I do not think that $3$ is considered to be a perfect power. If so, every positive integer would be a perfect power.

Comment: Well by Fermat's Last Theorem, $a$ and $b$ cannot be raised to the power $m$ for $m>2$. That's all I know...